# SQL not working unless multiple db_connect(); statements

Tags: php

In the past I've had no issues using one simple:

$link = db_connect();

in a single file with multiple SQL commands like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET...";

$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $link)
or die("Couldn't execute query.");

$sql2 = "UPDATE table2 SET...";

$sql_result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link)
or die("Couldn't execute query.");
```

Now any new file I create won't work without multiple/separate db_connects.  For example:

```
$link = db_connect();

$link2 = db_connect();

$sql = "UPDATE table SET...";

$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $link)
or die("Couldn't execute query.");

$sql2 = "UPDATE table2 SET...";

$sql_result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link2)
or die("Couldn't execute query.");
```

The old files with multiple mysql_queries referencing a single db_connect(); are still working fine.  What could have changed?

Thanks.

Updated to include the db_connect(); function:

```
function db_connect($db="database", $host="localhost", $user="user", $p="password") {

    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $p);

    if (!$dbcnx)
    {
    echo( "<p>Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</p>" );
    exit();
    }

    $database = @mysql_select_db($db, $dbcnx);
    if (!$db)
    {
    echo "<p>Unable to locate the database at this time.</p>";
    exit();
    }

return $dbcnx;
}
```

Comment: Since db_connect is not a default function we may need to see the source for it. Make sure the function is defined or the file containing the function is being included. And make sure you are not including/using a copy/paste of the function.

Comment: You should avoid `mysql_*()`. They are not very much maintained anymore and there are much better ways to access a MySQL-Server like `Mysqli`, or `PDO_MySQL`

Comment: Thanks, I've added the function in question.  Like I said older files with multiple queries work with a single call to the function but new ones require multiple calls.

Comment: Which of the error messages is shown? **couldn't execute query**, **could't select database**, **could't connect to server**?

Comment: Is there any chance that the files you have just created are included into the workflow after the first connection is closed/released?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have $links separated, add `true` as fourth `mysql_connect()` parameter:

```
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $p, true);
```

Additionally if you want to use different connections (different databases, users, passwords), you need to explicitly pass parameters to `db_connect()` second time:

```
$link2 = db_connect('database2', 'whateverthehost', 'user2', 'andhispassword');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted looks fine unless you have something **unset()** ing $link, assigning it a value, or something else that is making $link no longer pointing to the database.